# calling a javascript function on a JSTL 'form field'

Tags: javascript, jstl

I'm trying to replace some line feed characters with `<br />` tags.  I'm not sure how to call my function ?  Essentially in the head I have a function like this

```
<head>
    <script>
        function replaceLineFeedsFunction (param){
             return param.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
          }
    </script>
</head>
```

in the page I have a section like this (this is stripped down to the bare bones so I hope it still makes some technical sense)

```
<c:forEach items="${supplier.accounts}" var="supacc">
    <table id="${supacc.id}">
        <tr>
            <td>Account Title</td>
            <td>${supacc.title}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </c:forEach>
```

It is the text in ${supacc.title} that I would like to apply the function to as the field is rendered...  So something like this

```
 <c:forEach items="${supplier.accounts}" var="supacc">
    <table id="${supacc.id}">
        <tr>
            <td>Account Title</td>
            <td>replaceLineFeedsFunction(${supacc.title})</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </c:forEach>
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this.  It seems like it ought to be so simple but maybe I'm missing the point as I've tried a number of ways and all of them fail!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tag libraries to achieve the same result:

```
       <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>    
       <c:forEach items="${supplier.accounts}" var="supacc">
        <table id="${supacc.id}">
            <tr>
                <td>Account Title</td>
                <td>${fn:replace(supacc.title, '\n', '<br />')}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
       </c:forEach>
```